# Strange problem with std::cout

Tags: c++, iostream

I have 2 loops:

```
//Loop 1
for ( vector<string>::iterator iter = vecv.begin() ; iter != vecv.end()  ; iter++)
    {
        cout << "-----IN LOOP----" <<  *iter;
    }

//Loop 2
for ( vector<string>::iterator iter = vecv.begin() ; iter != vecv.end()  ; iter++)
    {
        cout << "-----IN LOOP----" <<  *iter << endl ;
    }
```

Now vecv is a string vector and contains 2 strings:

`65` and `A000` respectively.

Now the loop 1 Does not print anything, in fact the loop seems to not run at all.

However on adding the `endl` as you see in Loop 2, it gives this output:

```
-----IN LOOP----65
-----IN LOOP----$A000
```

What is happening exactly?

Mind you i am facing this problem only in Visual Studio 2010 and not Dev-C++!!

Comment: "in fact the loop seems to not run at all" > did you try putting IN LOOP 1 and IN LOOP 2 to distinguish and be sure it does not run?

Comment: How is this question related to c++0x? Please remove the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know it doesn't print anything without `endl`? By observing running program? If so, the problem is that `cout` provides buffered output: it actually prints somehting on the screen (or in the file) only when its buffer is full.

`endl` on other hands flushes the buffer.

If you want unbuffered output you can use `cerr`, but it would lead to some differences (like, now if you want to redirect output to file you should do `2>` instead of `>` etc.)

If you want buffered output but don't want to have newlines, print `flush` into `cout`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::endl` also flushes the buffer. If you want to flush without linebreak, use `std::flush`.

Comment: Thats ok... it flushes the buffer -  but why wont anything print?

Comment: @user: Because the text only shows up on the console once the buffer is flushed.

Comment: Then why do i not face the same problem in Dev-C++

Comment: I have no idea, never used that. But this information should have been part of your question.

Comment: @user667389 The exact policy regarding bufferization is implementation dependent, and implementations may do different things (starting with having different sized buffers).

Answer (score 0):

I think the `cout.clear()` just destroy the cout buffer. Since it has not been flushed therefore it's lost.

**EDIT 1: Code providing :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

  vector<string> vecv;

  vecv.push_back("abc");
  vecv.push_back("def");

  //Loop 1
  for ( vector<string>::iterator iter = vecv.begin() ; iter != vecv.end()  ; iter++)
  {
    cout << "-----IN LOOP 1----" <<  *iter;
  }

  //Loop 2
  for ( vector<string>::iterator iter = vecv.begin() ; iter != vecv.end()  ; iter++)
  {
    cout << "-----IN LOOP 2----" <<  *iter << endl ;
  }
}
```

outputs :

```
./a.out
-----IN LOOP 1----abc-----IN LOOP 1----def-----IN LOOP 2----abc
-----IN LOOP 2----def
```

Comment: Removed it. Still same issue.

Comment: Code provided for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing the full program, but I suspect that it ends with a 
`system("pause");`, as is often seen in tutorials for MSVC. MSVC runtime does not flush the output buffer when calling `system()` (it isn't required to), thus all output to `std::cout` remains buffered if no `std::flush`, `std::endl`, or input from `std::cin` were performed.

Try running your program in a console window (Start->Run->cmd.exe). The output should appear when the program terminates, even without `endl`.